# Python's argparser: how to set command line input of a positional argument as the default for an optional argument?

Tags: python, argparse

I want the command line input of a positional input to be the default for an optional argument, like this:

```
parser.add_argument("Foo")
parser.add_argument("-b", dest="bar")
parser.set_defaults(parser.Foo)

options = parser.parse_args()
```

Is something like this possible at all? Or should I just do something like:

```
parser.add_argument("Foo")
parser.add_argument("-b", dest="bar")
parser.set_defaults("same as Foo")

options = parser.parse_args()
if options.bar == "same as Foo":
    options.bar = options.Foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try like you do in the second block of code, but use `None` as the sentinel value rather than a magic string.

Comment: I want the help file to show that the default is the same as the positional input though.